# how to make world space UI crosshair line up with screen space crosshair?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make the gun on the turret of my tank point towards the center of the screen just like in World of tanks where you have a crosshair for where the gun is pointing and the crosshair for the center of the screen.

The problem is that the gun crosshair which is a UI image in world space parented to the gun, doesn't exactly line up with the center of the screen which is the big crosshair in the image [enter image description here][1].

edit: so this works but how can I change it to the x axis?

```
public class CenterCursor : MonoBehaviour
{
// speed is the rate at which the object will rotate
public float speed;

void FixedUpdate()
{

    // Generate a plane that intersects the transform's position with an upwards normal.
    Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);

    // Generate a ray from the cursor position
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    // Determine the point where the cursor ray intersects the plane.
    // This will be the point that the object must look towards to be looking at the mouse.
    // Raycasting to a Plane object only gives us a distance, so we'll have to take the distance,
    //   then find the point along that ray that meets that distance.  This will be the point
    //   to look at.
    float hitdist = 0.0f;
    // If the ray is parallel to the plane, Raycast will return false.
    if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
    {
        // Get the point along the ray that hits the calculated distance.
        Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);


        // Determine the target rotation.  This is the rotation if the transform looks at the target point.
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation( targetPoint - transform.position);

        // Smoothly rotate towards the target point.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just make the gun face the same direction as the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try putting your turret object as a child of camera object...

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.